# Referencing entity generic inside package in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to define a type inside a package whose size is dependent on the component generics. Here is what I am trying to do, but synthesis is complaining:

```
package DcoPack is
    component SinCosDco
    generic
    (
         g_LUT_DEPTH   : integer := 2**10;
         g_LUT_BIT_RES : integer := 15

    );
    port
    (
        reset       : in  std_logic;
        lClk        : in  std_logic;

        InFreqCtrl  : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"028F5C28";   
        InStartPhse : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"00000000";   

        OutDco      : out signed((g_LUT_BIT_RES - 1) downto 0)
    );


    type LutSinT is array(0 to g_LUT_DEPTH - 1) of 
            std_logic_vector(g_LUT_BIT_RES-1 downto 0);

    function f_QuantizationSgn(nbit : integer; max_abs : real; dval : real) 
    return std_logic_vector;

    function f_InitLutSin 
    return LutSinT;   
end package DcoPack;

package body DcoPack is
    function f_QuantizationSgn(nbit : integer; max_abs : real; dval : real) 
    return std_logic_vector is
        <function body>
    end function;

    function f_InitLutSin return LutSinT is
        <function body>
    end function;
end package body DcoPack;
```

and my component

```
library DCO_lib;
use DCO_lib.DcoPack.all;

entity Dco is
    generic
    (
         g_LUT_DEPTH   : integer := 2**10;
         g_LUT_BIT_RES : integer := 15
    );
    port
    (
        reset       : in  std_logic;
        lClk        : in  std_logic;

        InDcoEn     : in  std_logic;
        InFreqCtrl  : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"028F5C28";   
        InStartPhse : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"00000000";

        OutDco      : out signed((g_LUT_BIT_RES - 1) downto 0)
    );
end entity Dco;

architecture zDco of Dco is
    -- want to reference LutSinT in numerous components, it varies depending 
    -- on generics
    constant c_SinCosLut : LutSinT := f_InitLutSin;
... <rest of code is irrelevant
```

As the code above shows, I am trying to reference this type inside each component. However, I need to be able to easily vary the generic parameters depending on the project, so is there a way for VHDL to infer the correct array size? Or am I locked into defining the g_LUT_DEPTH/g_LUT_BIT_RES in the package or hard-coding the type inside each component?

EDIT: Added clarifying code snippets and explanation.

Comment: You don't provide a [mcve], nor a context clause, or end statements for the component declaration and package declaration and a specific problem ("complianing" isn't particularly enlightening). On the other hand IEEE Std 1076-2008 12.1 Declarative region "...A single declarative region is formed by the text of each of the following:...f) A component declaration..." 12.2 Scope of declarations para 2 (in part): "...The scope of a declaration, except for an architecture body, extends from the beginning of the declaration to the end of the immediately closing declarative region; ..." Not visible.

Comment: @user115120 my apologies, I didn't realize my objective wasn't clear. I'm currently on mobile and I don't have access to my code anymore. However, I am trying to reference that type inside my component SinCosDco. This package declares the components of my library, all types, and all functions. The package body only contains all of my functions behavior. This package sits in the same directory as my entity code. I map this directory as a library for sim/synth and include this library in my entity SinCosLut.

Comment: Your comment provides little additional clarity. The declaration for type LutSinT appears to be referencing g_LUT_DEPTH and g_LUT_BIT_RES, neither of which are visible at the place of type declaration either directly or by selection. It's unclear where you expect the values for the entity's generic map constants to come from, you can't reach into the virtual design entity (6.8 Component declarations) and reference it's generics outside it's scope.

Comment: @user1155120 Thank you for the response, and that is what I am hoping to solve. I am updating my post to make my objective more clear. My question: is it possible to reference a generic in a package somehow, or somehow get synth/sim to infer the correct size using range <>? I will be instantiating components in the pack body for numerous DCO's and want to access similar types in all of them without hard-coding them so-to-speak in each component body.

Comment: Move the type declaration for LutSinT and function body (sans function declaration) for f_InitLutSin to the entity declarative part (as entity declarative items after the port clause, IEEE Std 1076-2008 3.2 Entity declarations), can also be architecture declarative items (3.3.2 Architecture declarative part).  The entity generic constants will be visible for either. Interface package declarations  (6.5.6) associated with generic packages (6.5.7.2) are likely not widely supported for synthesis (if at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there now is. VHDL-2008 supports package generics. So you can write

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity SinCosDco is
    generic (
         g_LUT_DEPTH   : positive;
         g_LUT_BIT_RES : positive
         );
    port (
        OutDco      : out signed((g_LUT_BIT_RES - 1) downto 0)
        );
end entity;

architecture tmp of SinCosDco is
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
begin
    OutDco <= to_signed(-1, g_LUT_BIT_RES);
end architecture;


library ieee;

package DcoPack is
    generic (
         g_LUT_DEPTH   : positive := 2**10;
         g_LUT_BIT_RES : positive := 15
         );
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    component SinCosDco
        generic (
             g_LUT_DEPTH   : positive := g_LUT_DEPTH;
             g_LUT_BIT_RES : positive := g_LUT_BIT_RES
             );
        port (
            OutDco      : out signed((g_LUT_BIT_RES - 1) downto 0)
            );
    end component;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    type LutSinT is array(0 to g_LUT_DEPTH - 1) of std_logic_vector(g_LUT_BIT_RES-1 downto 0);

end package DcoPack;


entity e is end entity;

library ieee;

architecture a of e is
    constant g_LUT_DEPTH: positive := 2**7; -- remember integer is only 32 bits
    constant g_LUT_BIT_RES : positive := 8;

    package myDcoPack is new work.DcoPack
        generic map (
            g_LUT_DEPTH => g_LUT_DEPTH,
            g_LUT_BIT_RES => g_LUT_BIT_RES);
    -- use work.myDcoPack.all; -- optional

    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    signal output : signed((g_LUT_BIT_RES - 1) downto 0);
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    signal lut : myDcoPack.LutSinT;
begin
    comp_inst : myDcoPack.SinCosDco
        port map ( OutDco => output );

    lut(0) <= std_logic_vector(output);
end architecture;
```

However, this was not supported in Vivado 2 years ago. Don't know if it's supported now.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I'm looking for! Unfortunately I am using an old board for this project, so 14.7 doesn't have support for VHDL-2008, but I will put the hooks in for the toolset version when I upgrade.